# Compiling in Netbeans with errors

Tags: java, netbeans

I have a project in Netbeans. I currently have several Classes which I have been working on which are in the project but are not referenced by my Main class or any of its dependencies. Currently when I do a build from netbeans, it is saying it can not build because of errors in the unused classes.

How can I exclude these from the Build without removing them from the project?

Comment: Why not fix the errors that you're facing?

Comment: Why not just rename the file from "Foo.java" to "Foo.txt", then the IDE would no longer try to compile it.

Comment: So are we saying there is no way to do it in netbeans without a "hack"